# Why did Hudson Bay melt so late this year?

Tags: meteorology, cryosphere

[image: http://ice-glaces.ec.gc.ca/prods/WIS130CT/20150903115200_WIS130CT_0008451788.gif]

The fear with the polar bears is that the ice-free period in the bay is getting longer, right?

Did the consecutive polar vortex years from all this global weirding make the bay's winters colder? It was near-record cold as late as ~2/20/15 here but I'm 10-20° south of the bay, I don't know if the cooling effect of the wavy polar vortex extends that far north. It certainly makes the North Arctic warmer.

Comment: Please note that the "polar vortex" is a stratospheric circulation that is always present and not a surface feature.  It is a term grossly misused by media.